# Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll'

Tags: c#, arm

Пытался запустить проект на raspberry pi но он выдает такую ошибку, этот проект спокойно работал на обычном пк, но на малинке выдает ошибку.
Пробовал скидывать SQLite.Interop.dll рядом с самой программой но не помогает

Unhandled exception. System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'SQLite.Interop.dll' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: libSQLite.Interop.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Если у вас проблема с System.Data.SQLite (что может быть. там вроде самому нужно собирать под arm), то попробуйте Microsoft.Data.Sqlite (возможно даже preview)

Answer (score 0):

Для этого нужно самому скомпилировать ARM вариант Interop сборки.

1. Качаем исходники на малинку [отсюда](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki). Нужен архив вида sqlite-netFx-source-1.0.116.0.zip
2. Распаковываем
3. В директории `Setup` есть скрипт `compile-interop-assembly-release.sh` он соберет `libSQLite.Interop`
4. Если вдруг нужен докер - то я собрал сегодня альфу - `docker pull ghcr.io/ashchpi/docker-sqlite-netfx/aspnet:6.116` (.NET Core 6 + system.data.sqlite 1.0.116)